# Migrating a Laravel application from Windows to Linux

Tags: php, linux, laravel

I have built a simple site in laravel using Windows and php artisan serve. Everything worked just fine.

Now I am trying to keep building it on Linux, however it just won't work.

The new IP is something like this:

```
123.45.67.8/myproject/public/login
```

Whereas it should just be

```
123.45.67.8/myproject/login
```

What can I do?

Comment: "it just won't work" tells us absolutely nothing. What about it "doesn't work"? Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please post your error and problem**
Things to do in general and simple way.

1. First migrate files and folders to linux
2. check you web server is running
3. change your app path in you **.env** and configs in **config/app.php**
4. Make sure about **.htaccess** file inside public directory
5. Make sure about ReWrite engine on and Orride allowed for this site (httpd.conf or apache.conf if apache server)
6. Check your DB connection too

When migrating what i always do is simply copy my project files to linux machine and then update all configurations including server config and Laravel app configs. **Basic are database, laravel app path and url rewrite config (server side)**

Answer (score 0):

Remember to serve the public directory, not the root of the project, which actually is a security risk.

Example for an apache config part:

```
DocumentRoot "/home/vagrant/projects/myapp/public"
<Directory "/home/vagrant/projects/myapp/public">
  AllowOverride all
</Directory>
```